# Why can't hardly represent hardness?

Tags: word-usage

*Soft* is used to describe something that's soft.

- That ball is soft, I think we need to get some air into the ball.

*Hard* is used to describe something that's hard.

- The ball is now hard.

Or, to express strictness, eagerness, or difficulty.

- He's hard on his little girl.
- I work very hard.
- That game is so hard to complete.

*Softly* is used when something is handled softly or something like that.

- He closed the door softly.

BUT! *Hardly* won't work that way... as far as [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hardly) and [Cambrdige](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/hardly) goes, they don't mean or to express something's hardness. Instead, it'll be used like:

- I've hardly managed to complete the game.
- I hardly work. (It's complete opposite of "*I work very hard*"!)
- You're hardly hitting me.

What makes me confusing is, any other word like harden, harder, hardest, *can* mean to express something's hardness, or make something harder. Still, we can't use hardly in a sentence like this:

- He shut the door hard.

Why can't we just use *hardly* instead of *hard*? I do actually feel weird that if we use *hardly* in that sentence, but why? What is the origin of this?

In my native language, as far as I know we don't have "*softly*" equivalent word to close a door, but in English, we do. So why not close it "*hardly*"?

Comment: I suppose we don't use _hardly_ as an antonym of _softly_ because the other meaning (scarcely) has become so much more common.

Comment: @Void No, not really. Actually, when I was writing this question, ell's automated system suggested that question - I still couldn't find my *main* question's answer; My main question is, as my question's title says, "Why can't *hardly* represent the hardness of an object?", not that I am concerned about the difference between *hard* and *hardly*. And I understand the difference itself, I think.

Comment: @Skye: The title of the linked question is kinda misleading but the answers **do** answer your question. (They're more or less the same as the answer below which makes it a dupe of that one.)

Comment: @Void Ah. Sorry, I just read first answer and not the other one. Then indeed that answer answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that, a long time ago (~ 1200 AD) "hardly" was used to mean what we might expect it to mean : "in a hard manner; with great exertion or effort"

Over time, the meaning changed a little, but still related to hardness : "not easily; with trouble"

This new meaning quickly (~ 1540 AD) changed to the current meaning : "barely; just"

This gradual change in meaning is why we can hardly use "hardly" to mean "hardly" !!

Reference:
https://www.etymonline.com/word/hardly

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why it has changed like this... I guess only linguist knows it?

Comment: @Skye-AT: Because language is always changing and language change is unavoidable. For instance, [the word 'nice' once meant *ignorant* but today it means *pleasant/attractive/cool*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/535259/365490).

Comment: @Void Oh, yeah that's true. Here in my country, language is always changing and evolving. I think of language as a living organism, but I just wondered why it has changed that way.